# Possibility to continuously extend a derivative at a point where the function is not defined

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Is there such a thing as a continuous extension of the derivative at a non-defined point ?

I mean, is it possible to continuously extend the derivative at a non-defined point without even computing the derivative at the point ?

If it is possible, then I don't understand how.

PS: By non-defined point I mean that $f$ is defined on $I\backslash\{a\}$ and $a$ is the non-defined point.

Comment: Not if you can't define the value at $a$ such that the function is continuous and differentiable at $a$. For instance, if $f(x)=x^2$ for $x>0$ and $x^2-1$ for $x<0$, the limit of the derivative certainly exist from both sides, and it's the same limit. But how would you extend $f$ at $0$? If $f(x)=x^2$ for $x<0$, however, you *can* extend $f$ by defining $f(0)=0$, and the new function is differentiable at $0$. Of course, in the first case, $f'$ is a function (call it $g$), and you *could* extend $g$ by $g(0)=0$, but it's not related to a derivative anymore.

Comment: ok that makes perfect sense. thank you.